# Centralizing active elements that went beyond the scroll with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to center active elements that are inside a container with horizontal scroll.

When it exceeded the size of the scroll it would still be centered.

I'm trying with the code below, but it's not working very well.

I would like something like this: https://menu.ifood.com.br/efe97335-dd93-4bd2-88ad-30ffb2c4a5f7/catalog

[image]

```
// categories navigation
$(document).on('scroll', function (e) {
    $('.category-holder').each(function () {
        if (
            $(this).offset().top < window.pageYOffset + 140 &&
            $(this).offset().top + $(this).height() > window.pageYOffset + 140
        ) {
            let data = $(this).attr('id');

            $('.category-' + data)
                .siblings()
                .removeClass('active');

            $('.category-' + data).addClass('active');

            centerPosition($('.category-' + data));
        }
    });
});

function centerPosition(category) {
    let scroller = $('.categories');
    let scrollTo = {
        left: category.position().left,
        width: category.innerWidth(),
    };
    scroller.animate({ scrollLeft: scrollTo.left - scrollTo.width }, 0);
    console.log(scrollTo);
}
```

I changed the code to the one below, it improved a little, but it seems that there is a delay when getting the scroll coordinates and sometimes it returns the wrong value.

[**EDIT: SUCCESS**]
Got it, the code below is another edit, now it worked, even with a workaround lol. If you have a better version, please send it to us.

```
// categories navigation
let categoriesPosition = {};
$('.category-holder').each(function () {
    id = $(this).attr('id');
    pos = $('.category-' + id).position().left;

    categoriesPosition[id] = pos;
});
    
$(document).on('scroll', function (e) {
    $('.category-holder').each(function () {
        if (
            $(this).offset().top < window.pageYOffset + 140 &&
            $(this).offset().top + $(this).height() > window.pageYOffset + 140
        ) {
            let id = $(this).attr('id');
            let category = $('.category-' + id);

            if (!category.hasClass('active')) {
                category.siblings().removeClass('active');
                category.addClass('active');

                centerPosition(id, category);
            }
        }
    });
});

function centerPosition(id, category) {
    scroller = $('.categories');
    width = category.innerWidth();
    screen_size = $(window).width();

    scroller.animate(
        { scrollLeft: categoriesPosition[id] - screen_size / 2 + width / 2 },
        300
    );
}
```

Comment: the url you provide shows: You don't have permission to access "http://menu.ifood.com.br/efe97335-dd93-4bd2-88ad-30ffb2c4a5f7/catalog" on this server.

Comment: See if the gif I add helps

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you wanted, I might have misunderstood your question.

But using position of the element inside the scrolling container, you can calculate where it should scroll to.
Then you just need to detect what position you are in the content scroll, and use that to determine which element to scroll to in the horizontal category bar.

Not sure if this is better than your final version, but maybe it helps.

```
let cooldownTimer = null;
let categoryScroller = $('.category-container');
let categoryList = $('.category-list');

// In my codepen I scrolled on the .content instead of (document), but same idea
let viewDocument = $('.content');

$(viewDocument).on('scroll', (e) => {  
    $('.category-holder').each((index, element) => {        
      let currentDifference = $(viewDocument).height() - $(element).offset().top;
      
      // Scroll if content is in the top ~1/3rd of the content area
      if (currentDifference > 175 && currentDifference < 300
          || currentDifference > $(viewDocument).height() -150 ) {   
        
        // Select category when the user stops scrolling
        clearTimeout(cooldownTimer);
        cooldownTimer = setTimeout(() => {         
          let scrollerCurrentX = $(categoryScroller).scrollLeft();
          let category = $(`.category-${element.id}`);
          let categoryLeftX = $(category).position().left - categoryList.position().left;  
          let targetX = scrollerCurrentX - categoryLeftX;

          if (!$(category).hasClass('active')) { 
            $(category).siblings().removeClass('active');
            $(category).addClass('active');
          }
          moveToPosition(categoryScroller, categoryLeftX);
        }, 1000);
      }
    });
});

function moveToPosition(scroller, x) {  
  $(scroller).animate({ scrollLeft: x })    
}
```